# How to Display access database data in listview by date in descending order

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ms-access-2007

I am using list view to display access database data.

I am a column called Date.there are more than 360 days data each with a data

Example  Date , `date format = yyyyMMdd.` it is displaying ascending

```
20111104

20111105

20111106

20111107

20111108
```

I want to Display the data by date in descending order like this

```
20111108

20111107

20111106

20111105

20111104
```

I am using these code to display acces data in list view.

```
 try
   {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from MyTable", con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            int iRecords = 0;
            foreach (DataRow myrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem lItem = new ListViewItem();
                lItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                lItem = listviewTargets.Items.Insert(iRecords, Date.ToString());
                //Note in the above line "Date.ToString" is written
                lItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                // listviewTargets.Items.Add(myrow[2].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[0].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[3].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[14].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[4].ToString(), Color.White, Color.Green, lItem.Font);
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[6].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[7].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[8].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[9].ToString());
                iRecords++;
                lItem = listviewTargets.Items.Insert(iRecords, "");
                lItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

                //iRecords = iRecords - 1;
               // lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                lItem.SubItems.Add("");
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[5].ToString(), Color.White, Color.Red, lItem.Font);
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[10].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[11].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[12].ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(myrow[13].ToString());
                iRecords++;
            }
            //  gv_ViewAllEntries.DataSource = ds.Tables["MyTable"];
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from MyTable order by [Date] desc", con);
```

Comment: one min please i will check it

Comment: thanks its working i want to use             OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from realtimedata where (Name='" + Name + "')", con); with order because there are many names also

Comment: Then, again, take a look at [ORDER BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) and apply it yourself.

Comment: There already is an ORDER BY clause in my answer. If you want to order different queries, apply the clause yourself please.

Comment: i am very new in ms access database can u do it for me there would be a great appreciation if you helped me

Comment: Sorry, I'm a fan of "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime". I've shown how to do it on another query and supplied a link, the rest is up to you. Or will you return to SO with a question for every query you need to be ordered?